# Don't see mobile app requests via Charles

Tags: ssl, charles-proxy

I've got all the setting right. But i can't check traffic just for one app which with i work. They are not displayed at all, no errors, no ssl lock, and no requests)
For another apps, charles has intercepts all requests.
Maybe someone faced such a problem. Requests aren't showed for iOS and Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why Charles doesn't capture traffic from your iOS/Android Devices.

You might check the following list:

1. Turn OFF all VPN from your iOS Devices -> Many people forget this thing.
2. Check the IP in Proxy in your Wifi
3. Turn OFF the Firewall on macOS (Sometimes, it's on and block all incoming traffic)
4. Your company might block port 8888 where Charles is listening

You can see the [troubleshooting](https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/my-ios-devices-couldnt-connect-to-proxyman-via-proxy) page, which covers other reason and how to fix it.

It's from Proxyman, but it's still applied to Charles Proxy.